# Package dependency problem while installing ROS in Ubuntu Natty (11.04)

Tags: ubuntu-natty, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just saw the public Debian distribution of ROS for Ubuntu Natty, which I have been waiting for for a long time. However, I cannot install ros-diamondback-ros-comm, because it requires a package called "libkrb5-dev", which requires "krb5-multidev", which has the following dependency errors that cannot be resolved:

krb5-multidev:

Depends: libkrb5-3 (=1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.1 is to be installed

Depends: libk5crypto3 (=1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.1 is to be installed

Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (=1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.1 is to be installed

I have noticed that these three packages are pre-installed as "version 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.1" by Ubuntu (11.04 amd64). I tried the force version, but it caused system error and made me reinstall the whole system. Is anyone encountering similar issue? I appreciate any suggestions that help me solve this dependency problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10138/package-dependency-problem-while-installing-ros-in-ubuntu-natty-(11.04)/) by [tbocs](https://answers.ros.org/users/622/tbocs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-06-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are the only direct dependencies of ros-comm on natty.  This sounds like there is something else going on with your Natty installation (maybe you are using an external ppa or something):

```
libc6, build-essential, cmake, python-yaml, subversion, python-numpy, python-imaging, python-paramiko, libapr1-dev, libaprutil1-dev, liblog4cxx10-dev, libbz2-dev, pkg-config
```

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2